# How do I make it so that I can run this program anywhere?

Tags: linux, unix, symlink

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

~/src/yuicompressor-2.4.2/build$ ls
yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar
```

Usually, I have to be in that directory to run this command. Is there any way I can set it so that I can run this command **anywhere** in my box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
cd ~/src/yuicompressor-2.4.2/
JAR=`pwd`/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar
JAVA=`which java`
echo "$JAVA -jar $JAR" > yuicompressor.sh
chmod +x yuicompressor.sh
sudo ln -s yuicompressor.sh /bin/yuicompressor.sh
```

now you (and other users) should be able to run yuicompressor.sh from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you could make an alias:

alias yuicomp=java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

you would need to put the full path in asw ell I think